# Refine LINQ join of two List<T> Objects, Group, and Count

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have two List objects. I want a count of how many items between the two list match. Now I could loop through with a counter as I come across matches....but that would be kinda lame.

However this one is stretching my LINQ knowledge. I believe what I want to do is Join, discern (where), group, and project the count. I came to this approach by reading similar SO questions and LINQ documentation.

However if this is flawed by all means it doesn't have to be this way. I just want the count of matching elements.

So my "master" object is:

```
public class Master
{
    public StringModel OldText { get; private set; }
    public StringModel NewText { get; private set; }

    public Master()
    {
        OldText = new StringModel();
        NewText = new StringModel();
    }
}
```

StringModel is:

```
public class StringModel
{
    public List<strPiece> Lines { get; private set; }

    public StringModel()
    {
        Lines = new List<strPiece>();
    }
}
```

My LINQ thus far is:

```
var unchangedJoin = from oldLine in Master.OldText.Lines
                    join newLine in Master.NewText.Lines
                    on oldLine.Type equals newLine.Type
                    where oldLine.Type == "ABC"
                    group oldLine by --as you can see I kinda break down here.
```

Any help finishing would be appreciated. Also if I need to post more code just let me know.
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform a `GroupJoin` rather than a `Join`.

```
var unchangedJoin = from oldLine in Master.OldText.Lines
                    join newLine in Master.NewText.Lines
                    on oldLine.Type equals newLine.Type
                    into newMatches
                    where oldLine.Type == "ABC"
                    select oldLine;

var matches = unchangedJoin.Count();
```

Comment: Very cool and it clicked instantly in my head because you used the model I was familiar with in your answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good use for [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399392(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var infoQuery =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    select cust.Country)
    .Intersect
        (from emp in db.Employees
        select emp.Country)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I too would recommend `Intersect`.  If you go that way, using the fluent syntax makes more sense.

```
int matches = Master.OldText.Lines
    .Where(line => line.Type == "ABC")
    .Intersect(Master.NewText.Lines)
    .Count();
```